# My camera rotates with my ball when i have ball as a parent gameobject of camera. what should i do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using my camera as a child gameobject of my ball, so when I move my ball camera comes with him. But the problem is I'm using `rigidbody.addForce()`, so when ball rotates the camera rotates with it, too.
So what should I do not to rotate my camera but only move it with my ball?

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.addForce(Input.getAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.getAxis("vertical")); 
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you using `addForce()`? Please post your code

Comment: I use this script in my ball object and main camera is child object.

Void FixedUpdate()
{
   rigidbody.addForce(Input.getAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.getAxis("vertical"));
}

Comment: Well, don't make your camera a child of the ball. At most write a script that allows your camera to follow a specific target.

Comment: and....that script would be???

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, I'll list a few.

The first, if you don't care if your ball rotates or not, you can just disable the rotation on the ball. If you open the Constraints section in the rigidbody component, you can freeze the rotation so that the ball won't rotate.

Alternatively, you can write a script that keeps the camera always oriented a certain way. Depending on if you want the camera to rotate around the ball on any plane depends on the way you would implement this.

The third option, which is cleanest, is to not have the camera be a child of the ball. A minimal component to do this would look like this:

```
public class TargetFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target;
    public float DistanceFromTarget;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Target.position + new Vector3(0, 0, DistanceFromTarget);
        transform.LookAt(Target);
    }
}
```

Just drag your ball into the 'Target' slot in your component. Keep in mind, this is super bare bones. You may want to add more variables to better control the direction the camera should be from the ball, or perhaps something that grabs a snapshot of the direction and distance the camera is from the ball in the Start method.